# Chat room reputation display mismatch

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, user-interface, chat

The screenshot below is taken from a [CRUDE message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49296184#49296184).  What does the number **17.4k** mean under the commentator?

[image]

My try:

I guess it would be the *highest* per se reputation.  However, [his/her main site user profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/468350/xander-henderson) shows that he/she has reputation **14.8k < 17.4k**.

---

Edit:

I would love to use myself as an example, but many messages in [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude) has *no* reputation displayed.  This time, I'm follow quid's advice and I use myself as an example.

[image]

Comment: The badges are also mismatched. See https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/300394/xander-henderson

Comment: Maybe it's the network-wide reputation?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thanks for comments.  Nice catch for the badge mismatch!

Comment: I find it slightly strange that somebody else is put on display here. You could just as well have used yourself as example.

Comment: @quid Please see my [edit] in response to your comment.  I'll take your advice into consideration next time and consider my own account first as an example in [meta] discussion.

Comment: I see. It seems only longer blocks where there is  enough space get the points in addition. I never realized that. The chat profile displays it also https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/180155/gnusupporter-8964- But the existence of that might not be obvious either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said already, the rep score under any chat user is the network-wide reputation. Note that reputation from other Stack Exchange communities is included even if it is less than 200 rep. This applies to badges as well.

Perhaps this is obvious, but the stated rep score under a chat message does not change after the user earns more rep - it will be updated in their next post. And it will only be displayed if the message is over three lines long.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, I've realised that it's in fact the **total network-wide reputation**.

Comment: Related posts on Meta Stack Exchange: [Chat reputation in left bar seems different than any other reputation displayed for users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100540). (The answer confirms this explanation.)

Comment: ... which makes sense, because the URL is chat.stackexchange.com and not math.chat.stackexchange.com